What is the short story which includes the sentence, "The melgerizer was only dangerous during the full of the moon"?
That's all I can remember. Perhaps somebody out there can pull off a miracle and ID this tale for me. :-)

A nice easy find if you search for the words "the melgerizer" as a keyword (i.e. with quote marks around it) on Google Books; https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+melgerizer%22. To be honest I was expecting to have to play around with different variants of the spelling but you remembered it perfectly.

Protection by Robert Sheckley. Originally published in Galaxy Science Fiction (1956), but you probably read it in the collection Pilgrimage to Earth

Things had been quiet for a few weeks. I had held off the feegs by the simple expedient of keeping my closet doors closed. The leeps were more menacing, but the eye of a toad seemed to stop them. And the melgerizer was dangerous only in the full of the Moon.


Someone remembered the megerizer and not lesnerizing?
